# Ball Weighing Riddle logic

Tags: algorithm, logic

A twist on the classic, "how many weighings to find the odd weight ball in 9 balls".

Suppose there is n balls. There are two types of balls. One type weighs less than the other. In the set of balls there is at least one of each ball. What is the least amount of weighing needed to separate the two different set of balls.

I am thinking at least n weighings since we do not know how many of each ball there are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a brain teaser, not a programming question. Try asking on the Puzzling Stack Exchange, http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the solution for 9 is 3?

Comment: @svs . . . The solution for 9 is 2.  This is a famous(ish) problem posed by Martin Gardner and mentioned in an op/ed in today's New York Times (http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/12/opinion/the-importance-of-recreational-math.html?ref=opinion&_r=0).

Comment: @GordonLinoff how is the solution 2? First you weight 4, 4 coins. If they are equal the 9th is the fake. Then you take the lighter 4-coin group and split it in two then again in two, no?

Comment: @svs The solution 2 is for the "9 coins with one lighter counterfeit coin" puzzle. Weigh 3 against 3, if equal the other 3 have the lighter coin; then weigh 1 against 1, if equal the third coin is the lighter one. The puzzle in the question is quite different, though.

Answer (score 0):

For every possible combination of balls, you can model the problem using a tree that describes which weighings are made and what conclusions about the weight distribution can be drawn from it. The minimal number of weighing is then determined by the minimal height of this tree.

I'm not going to spoil you the fun, so this description is intentionally left vague. Using this approach is also a brute-force approach and using a smarter approach could be beneficial, but I'll leave that to you.